# Duplicates at index[0] of tuples within a list, comparing a value of the duplicates, returning list of duplicates with the lowest value

Tags: python, list, duplicates, compare

I currently have a list of tuples, with the following syntax:

```
List = [(FID, LEVEL, REL_SIZE),(FID, LEVEL, REL_SIZE), ...]
```

So for instance:

```
List = [(22, 0, 40.210), (23, 0, 43.193), (23, 1, 80.867), (40, -1, 32.159), (40, 0, 50.408)]
```

What I need for my python code is to find all duplicates of FID (index 0), from the duplicates compare the REL_SIZE (index 2) and return the tuple with the lowest value for REL_SIZE in a new list.

So as a return of above example:

```
New_list = [(23, 0, 43.193), (40, -1, 32.159)]
```

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried.

Comment: In your returned new_list, what happens to the tupple (22, 0-, 40.210) ?

Comment: The OP only wants a list of tuples whose `FID` has duplicates.

Comment: the tuple ( 22, 0, 40.210) should be dropped out of the return, as in the return should only contain the duplicates with the lowest value for REL_size.

Comment: @Skiffel as per your question, 'from the duplicates' means that tupple with 22 as FID is not even considered, as there is only 1 tupple with FID 22 for comparison so which would mean that it would not be dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby()`

```
from itertools import groupby
List = [(22, 0, 40.210), (23, 0, 43.193), (23, 1, 80.867), 
        (40, -1, 32.159), (40, 0, 50.408)]

groups = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(List), key=lambda t:t[0])]
x = [min(g, key=lambda t:t[2]) for g in groups if len(g) > 1]
```

Produces:

```
[(23, 0, 43.193), (40, -1, 32.159)]
```

EDIT: <strike>Your clarification comment adds a wrinkle.  This will include the (22,...) tuple even though there are no duplicates.</strike> Fixed.

Comment: Your output is not the same as the `New_list` in the question.

Comment: you can check the `len` of `g` you are getting and filter out the `1`s

Comment: Updated per the OP's comments.

Comment: I have tested this on my list of tuples and this solution works for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We'll use a dictionary to group the tuples by FID.  Then we go back over the values of that dictionary, and take the minimum REL_SIZE of those with more than one tuple.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

l = [(22, 0, 40.210), (23, 0, 43.193), (23, 1, 80.867), (40, -1, 32.159), (40, 0, 50.408)]

d = defaultdict(list)
for t in l:
    d[t[0]].append(t)

print([min(tups, key=itemgetter(2)) for tups in d.values() if len(tups) > 1])
# [(40, -1, 32.159), (23, 0, 43.193)]
```

The drawback to this method is that you can lose the order of your input list, depending on what version of Python you use.

Comment: I was hoping the OP would have posted some code before someone revealed the right answer.